# Custom content entity route or url alias

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I'm not certain if I'm over-complicating something or just missing something or other.

Essentially, and in addition to a separate admin view of my custom entities, I want to assign a URL to them at the root of the site (i.e. /entity01).

I tried creating a URL property, but getting a route to respond to that is proving challenging. I tried adding a route like:

```
my_entities.entity_page:
  path: '/{entity_url}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::view'
    _title: 'Hello'
  options:
    parameters:
      entity_url:
        type: entity_url
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I have a custom a custom parameter converter set up as in:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/implementing-custom-parameter-converters

... and in the `convert` method, I can use an injected service to load my entity, etc. But in the `applies` method, I would like to see if it even matches any of my entities and return true or false appropriately, but the `applies` method doesn't seem to have the value of the URL parameter like the `convert` method does.

And even if I solve that, the above example only works with a path like:

```
path: '/my/{entity_url}'
```

If I remove the `/my` it doesn't work - I assume because it is conflicting with another route?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe this was asked recently, but your route cannot start with a parameter like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this with the pathauto (path alias?) module.  Go to the Admin -> Config -> Search / Metadata -> URL Aliases.  In the settings tab, enable your custom entity type.

When you edit them, you should have a URL field added.  You can also use the patterns to define default paths if you want.

I did a quick test with an ECK custom entity and it worked.

Comment: Wow ... I can't believe I didn't look there. I really thought I'd have to put the URL alias field in some manner myself, but it took care of it. Only 2 more issues I'll have: I really wanted a separate (or additional) view of the entity from the admin view (I suppose I can give this one a different theme) and I have some sub-pages I'll need off of this (i.e. /{entity_url}/subpage. I may have a lead on the latter issue. Thanks!